# Why am I not able to install PIP in my windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I don't know where the previous installation occurred?

C:\Users\intel\Desktop>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached

```
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 446, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 54, in install_given_reqs
    uninstalled_pathset = requirement.uninstall(
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 535, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 67, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc1qohh_\pip.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 86, in uninstallation_paths
    for row in r:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Backtracking, your previously installed PIP should be in the following path:

```
 C：\ Users \ intel \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ tmpdc1qohh_ \ pip.zip
```

Please try to remove it and reinstall it.